# Question about best way to establish a specific database design

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've looked around on the Stack Exchange websites and I've found 2 websites where I can ask this question. https://dba.stackexchange.com/ and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ . Now normally I think **Database administrators** would be the best place to put it, but then I looked on the website and saw a lot of questions that don't really relate to my question. So I went looking on Stack Exchangeand and I found **Programmers** and I read the tour part:

> Programmers Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professionals and students in software development and related fields who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software development.

So I was thinking I do need "expert answers on questions about software development and/or related fields," since I need the best way to establish a specific database design.

But my question has so much to do with Databases, that I can't figure out where to ask it.

Where should I ask this question?

Comment: Ask on Programmers. I once asked a DB schema question there too.

Comment: Have you looked at [database questions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdatabase%5D+closed%3A0) on Programmers? Reading the help center is a good first step, but it's not always all you need to do to get a clear idea if your question belongs on the site.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your uncertainty over this topic, I've found myself in similar situations where the right site won by a tight margin.

The topic does overlap DBA and Programmers SE, but if you consider your design question as conceptual, then [Programmers SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) sounds like the site you are looking for. Although I dare say that your question would be well received on DBA as well, I still recommend Programmers.

For future reference and readers... Adding a tiny bit of detail about the question you are asking would make it significantly easier to recommend you a proper site. Also it is a great idea what you did, to check the site and get first hand impression of what kind of questions are asked there.